# Spring Batch FlatFileItemWriter leaves empty file

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have the following code:

```
File overitimeFile = new File(filePath+overtimeFileName);
FlatFileItemWriter<OvertimeSAPExport> overtimeItemWriter = 
                                         new FlatFileItemWriter<OvertimeSAPExport>();
overtimeItemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(overitimeFile));
overtimeItemWriter.setShouldDeleteIfExists(true);
PassThroughLineAggregator<OvertimeSAPExport> lineAggregator = 
                                        new PassThroughLineAggregator<OvertimeSAPExport>();
overtimeItemWriter.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);
overtimeItemWriter.open(new ExecutionContext());

List<OvertimeSAPExport> overtimeList = overtimeDAO.getSapOvertimeData(locationId, month);
overtimeItemWriter.write(overtimeList);
```

I have implemented the toString method for OvertimeSAPExport and when I debug I can see that it enters the toString once for each record in the list and gets te correct string from it.
It also creates the file without problems and throws no exceptions my way, but when I look at the file, it's empty.

Could someone PLEASE show me where my mistake is?

Answer (score 0):

Try overtimeItemWriter.close(); and see if the file is flushed on disk.  You also need to validate if a transaction is ongoing that postponed the writing.

Comment: How to check a transaction is ongoing?